# Is it really necessary to nullify objects in JUnit teardown methods?

Tags: java, junit

I was intrigued by the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653589/junit-should-i-assign-null-to-resources-in-teardown-that-were-instantiated-in-s/3653734#3653734) to a similar question.  I believe it is incorrect.  So I created some test code.  My question is, does this code prove/disprove/inconclusive the hypothesis that it is useful to nullify member variables in teardown methods?  I tested it with JUnit4.8.1.

JUnit creates a new instance of the test class for each of the 4 tests.  Each instance contains an Object obj.  This obj is also inserted as the key of a static WeakHashMap.  If and when JUnit releases its references to a test instance, the associated obj value will become weakly referenced and thus eligible for gc.  The test tries to force a gc.  The size of the WeakHashMap will tell me whether or not the objs are gc'ed.  Some tests nullified the obj variable and others did not.

```
import org . junit . Before ;
import org . junit . After ;
import org . junit . Test ;
import java . util . ArrayList ;
import java . util . WeakHashMap ;
import java . util . concurrent . atomic . AtomicInteger ;
import static org . junit . Assert . * ;

public class Memory
{
    static AtomicInteger idx = new AtomicInteger ( 0 ) ;

    static WeakHashMap < Object , Object > map = new WeakHashMap < Object , Object > ( ) ;

    int id ;

    Object obj ;

    boolean nullify ;

    public Memory ( )
    {
    super ( ) ;
    }

    @ Before
    public void before ( )
    {
    id = idx . getAndIncrement ( ) ;
    obj = new Object ( ) ;
    map . put ( obj , new Object ( ) ) ;
    System . out . println ( "<BEFORE TEST " + id + ">" ) ;
    }

    void test ( boolean n )
    {
    nullify = n ;
    int before = map . size ( ) ;
    gc ( ) ;
    int after = map . size ( ) ;
    System . out . println ( "BEFORE=" + before + "\tAFTER=" + after ) ;
    }

    @ Test
    public void test0 ( )
    {
    test ( true ) ;
    }

    @ Test
    public void test1 ( )
    {
    test ( false ) ;
    }

    @ Test
    public void test2 ( )
    {
    test ( true ) ;
    }

    @ Test
    public void test3 ( )
    {
    test ( false ) ;
    }

    @ After
    public void after ( )
    {
    if ( nullify )
        {
        System . out . println ( "Nullifying obj" ) ;
        obj = null ;
        }
    System . out . println ( "<AFTER TEST " + id + ">" ) ;
    }

    /**
     * Try to force a gc when one is not really needed.
     **/
    void gc ( )
    {
    ArrayList < Object > waste = new ArrayList < Object > ( ) ;
    System . gc ( ) ; // only a suggestion but I'll try to force it
    list :
    while ( true ) // try to force a gc
        {
        try
            {
            waste . add ( new Object ( ) ) ;
            }
        catch ( OutOfMemoryError cause )
            {
            // gc forced? should have been
            waste = null ;
            break list ;
            }
        }
    System . gc ( ) ; // only a suggestion but I tried to force it
    }
}
```

I ran the code using the command line interface (utilizing the -Xmx128k option to increase garbage collection) and got the following result

```
.<BEFORE TEST 0>
BEFORE=1    AFTER=1
Nullifying obj
<AFTER TEST 0>
.<BEFORE TEST 1>
BEFORE=2    AFTER=1
<AFTER TEST 1>
.<BEFORE TEST 2>
BEFORE=2    AFTER=1
Nullifying obj
<AFTER TEST 2>
.<BEFORE TEST 3>
BEFORE=2    AFTER=1
<AFTER TEST 3>
```

The Test0 obj was nullified and in Test1 it is gc'ed.  But the Test1 obj was not nullified and it got gc'ed in Test2.  This suggests that nullifying objects is not necessary.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

JUnit 4.x style tests and test suites handle this differently than JUnit 3.x test suites.

In short, you **should set fields to null in JUnit3-style tests** but **you do not need to in JUnit4-style tests**.

With JUnit 3.x style tests, a `TestSuite` contains references to other `Test` objects (which may be `TestCase` objects or other `TestSuite` objects). If you create a suite with many tests, then there will be hard references to all of the leaf `TestCase` objects for the entire run of the outermost suite. If some of your TestCase objects allocate objects in `setUp()` that take up a lot of memory, and references to those objects are stored in fields that are not set to `null` in `tearDown()`, then you might have a memory problem.

In other words, for JUnit 3.x style tests, the specification of which tests to run references the actual `TestCase` objects. Any objects reachable from a `TestCase` object will be kept in memory during the test run.

For JUnit 4.x style tests, the specification of which tests to run uses [Description](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/Description.html) objects. The `Description` object is a value object that specifies what to run, but not how to run it. The tests are run by a `Runner` object that takes the `Description` of the test or suite and determines how to execute the test. Even the notification of the status of the test to the test listener uses the `Description` objects.

The default runner for JUnit4 test cases, [JUnit4](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/JUnit4.html), keeps a reference to the test object around only for the duration of the run of that test. If you use a custom runner (via the `@RunWith` annotation), that runner may or may not keep references to the tests around for longer periods of time.

Perhaps you are wondering what happens if you include a JUnit3-style test class in a JUnit4-style [Suite](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Suite.html)? JUnit4 will call `new TestSuite(Class)` which will create a separate `TestCase` instance per test method. The runner will keep a reference to the `TestSuite` for the entire life of the test run.

In short, if you are writing JUnit4-style tests, do not worry about setting your test case's fields to `null` in a tear down (do, of course, free resources). If you are writing JUnit3-style tests that allocate large objects in `setUp()` and store those objects in fields of the `TestCase`, consider setting the fields to `null`.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Nullifying is necessary (to avoid memory leakage) in JUnit 3.x.  If you use JUnit4.x and the default runner nullifying is not necessary.  If you use a custom runner, then you may need to nullify.

Answer (score 0):

**No it is not necessary.**

Tear-down methods are for life-cycled objects that likes to be explicitly closed, terminated, shutdown, disposed, disconnected, unregistered or whatever.

Even if your references survive to the next test case, they will be overwritten by your set-up method and become unreferenced and thus eligible for garbage collection.

And event if JUnit creates a new instance of your test case for every method (which seems to be the case), those test objects are not held on to. At least not if the test passes, according to a quick experiment. So the lot of it will be collected at leisure anyway.

Comment: Both JUnit3 style tests and JUnit4 style tests create a separate object per test method that is executed, so unless the references are stored in statics (not recommended) the references will not be overwritten by the next set-up method

Comment: @NamshubWriter is that a guarantee or an implementation detail? If the latter then it might change (though unlikely). Regardless, these instances aren't kept around (in JUnit 4.8.1, according to experiment) — at least not if the test passes.

Comment: It's not an implementation detail, it's the documented behavior. JUnit does this so it's harder to have the result of one test affect the behavior of another test.