# Spring Framework - Unit testing design

Tags: unit-testing, spring, maven-2, garbage-collection, transactional

I'm writing to try and initiate a bit of a discussion regarding Spring Unit testing and in particular Transactional unit tests.

We currently have around 441 tests in a variety of classes annotated like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/context/ServiceTest-context.xml"}, inheritLocations=false)
public class ServiceTests extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {}

    @Test
    public void testSomethingElse() {}
}
```

Each of our tests classes have their own test context.

We're facing an issue in which when we run individual test classes or individual packages the tests run fine.

However when we want to scale that up to run ALL our tests (currently > 400) by using maven or something similar such as Hudson integration.

```
mvn test
```

We get to a point and then start to experience Java GC Limit exceeded errors.

Now I get the feeling that this is down to our test plan design rather than the need for us to up any memory limits or turn off the warnings.

Can anyone share their experiences and the way they solved a similar problem?

Eggsy

Comment: Do you share the test context between the individual tests and use a specific forkmode configuration ? see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkMode

Comment: The test contexts are shared between individual tests however they're aren't shared between individual test classes/suites. We generally have a test class that uses one context and then there a multiple tests within that class which use the same context. Does that make sense? We don't use a specific forkmode config - what does that do? (Having never used that Maven option)

Comment: Useful link for anyone looking for forkMode info (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/class-loading.html)

Comment: did you check some existing questions for "Java GC Limit exceeded" like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/what-does-the-error-message-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceed ? basically it boils down to too much (temporary) objects

Comment: Hi there, I did but my question was more intended as a general design discussion in the context of Spring unit testing rather than specifics. I have a hunch it is the different contexts we use holding onto beans which is consuming all the memory hence the nature of the question.

Comment: i am still not sure if it is a spring only problem, you talk about 441 tests, how much spring beans has a context ? 100 ? 500 ? are we talking about singletons (500 would be a lot) ? do you create 1000s of prototype beans ? - could be one cause for the gc limit error, do you have 1000s of jpa  objects - maybe with many 1:n relations, and huge lists for each object ?

Comment: Did you take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655944/is-it-really-necessary-to-nullify-objects-in-junit-teardown-methods?  That thread notes a distinct difference in object lifecycles between Junit versions 3 and 4.

Comment: No but I shall take a look at it now and see if any of the difference affect our memory usage. Thank you.

Comment: In my opinion this can be a super interesting question, especially if its focused on **discussing guidelines about unit testing design for Spring applications**.

Comment: Have you considered forking Java for each test in the Maven config?

Comment: Hi there, can you explain by what you mean by forking java? Yes this question was more intended as a discussion about the best way to design tests rather than my specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the container will hold on to all the contexts for the duration of the its lifecycle unless you explicitly call appCtx.close()

Is there some particular reason that every test has its own context? Because unless you have a special reason for doing that....I'd say,  don't do that. As long as you have appropriate setup and teardown methods, you should be able to share. Even if you group similar tests together and have just those share contexts. More info please!